# Removing this filter added by a plugin

Tags: plugins, actions

I found the action I'd like to remove in the plugin php file:

```
add_action('init', array($user_hooks, "doAutoLogout"));
```

yet, when I add this:

```
remove_action('init', array($user_hooks, "doAutoLogout"));
```

to my `functions.php`, the action remains.

I'm 99% sure I'm targeting the right action, so I think it may be something else. Anything obvious?

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct way to do this, turns out. I'm not sure why it didn't at first. May be the caching plugin.